# Convert a std::string in C++ so its can be a byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, c++

So, I'm trying to encrypt a message in C++ and decrypt in C#..
My decryption in C# needs the Key and IV in bytes, and in C++ I set the Key and IV with std::string and later in the encryption I use this:
`(byte*)key.c_str()`

How can i get this Key

```
std::string szEncryptionKey = "Sixteen byte key";
```

How can I hardcode this into C#

```
 byte[] key = ????
```

So it uses the right Key and IV to decrypt?

Comment: Despite any convenience methods and any "conceptual implicit casting" between `char`s and bytes, encryption takes bytes as both the data and the key and produces bytes. There is no text but encoded text, so if you are using text to create such bytes, you have to use a specific character encoding and share that knowledge all around. In the case of a string literal, the encoding is the "destination charset" that your compiler uses for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Encoding` class in the namespace `System.Text` provides a method to retrieve the `byte` representation of a `string` or a `char[]`.

You can use it like this:

```
Byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc");
```

There are other encodings like `UTF32` available, if needed.

EDIT: I've checked the contents of `b`: for the encodings `UTF7`, `UTF8`, `ASCII` and (my current) `Default` the byte values for the string "abc" are the same: `97`, `98` and `99`. `UTF32` only adds three zeros; the output is `97 0 0 0`, `98 0 0 0` and `99 0 0 0`.

Comment: But with this, I need to know the exact same encoding that's being done in c++? but I'm not sure which one?

Comment: @KunoHeltborg in Visual C++ it is most likely UTF8

Comment: @KunoHeltborg I have updated the answer with some results of different encodings.

Comment: Okay, is there anyway I can check that this ; (byte*)key.c_str().. is giving me the same byte stream as this Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc");..

Comment: Just to see the output of this (byte*)key.c_str(). The part from C# is simple enough to see :)

Comment: You can print each byte to a console and check if the numbers are equal, or you can 'convert' it back to a string. In C#: `String s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b)` where `b` is the byte array.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is, because my decryption is not working and I think it could be this encoding problem

Comment: You could write the results of the encryption to a text file and see what it looks like. Do you have an example of it?

Comment: I was more thinking about seeing the byte stream in C++, because with this `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b);` I clealy see the result of the byte stream.. But if c++ is not using utf8, it will have a different byte stream when encrypt and decrypt.. So I would like to compare the byte streams, and now I just need to see the byte stream from the c++ part

Comment: Then try to output the result from the c++ part; as already suggested.

Comment: ` CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
  new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
   new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),` This is encoding to b64 so I cant see the byte stream

Comment: @KunoHeltborg if this answer is not working for you, then maybe you should post another question that asks about the specific problem you encounter.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Okay, I just thought this could give me a more technical idea of whats going on :)

Comment: Sebastian, this is my output q�"��=+"��L�B�� 2h��b<�҃���

Comment: Could you please show me the Base64 string (the encoded version, not the decoded)? I'd like to test something with it...

Comment: cboiiqATFAU9KyK49BJMmkLLwiAyaP6yYjyM0oP09xbITLGaxRuLCsTYYzUKANydhO+JO7N00aVz0tmFTjl3OClkO0e9P16NO1HfQFVP5NgNnuEIGzi7yWXw3sRj+cWOBBMsWZqUsiZOcARCY1tKp/IinarBfka6gJ10h9c1SCaB9wIcM4nRnYGjtBa70DZpBKH2NwCUAa5939tkKqK6bchkVoUFfZ+GJ1m8ZG0eJCLCjzBAg2oWMl1ywmhrZ0C9sOuy3SuuFBeUkZU+BAiJHZfHgAxa56P4Jf/i+mXkVU5xO4M6K/cfNq0SFzhLzbvn0+DSNtKsH08rlH1/uxmLKxZ/c2ENPdoj5WkOKK1/dxHo3QmDWC9wRAiJnACxgckF08ItrKf2B4Yr67AaVyRr1CEqh3Eq66B35ByWT/kA+hFO4owrPBDyDpEBI50UqQ7B/dXI4b0vRmevTdU3nzMjEpv9R+WWf8JRMsByg8fk9lMXpe0kg38=

Comment: I see; I was wondering why it looks like this. :)
Then of course you also need to decrypt it from AES to get a readable result...

Comment: Sebastian, I tried to show my problem in a new question instead, with code too.. Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175069/wrong-aes-decryption-when-trying-to-decrypt-in-another-language

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::string` is a wrapper of an array of `char` you can use it as an input to .NET [`Marshal.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) with a function similar to this (in C++/CLI):

```
array<System::Byte>^ stoa(const std::string& str)
{
    array<System::Byte>^ result = gcnew array<System::Byte>(str.size());
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(System::IntPtr((void*)str.c_str()), 
                                                    result, 0, result->Length);
    return result;
}
```

Or a C# version, assuming you have your `str::string::c_str` and string length pointer some other way (P/Invoke?):

```
byte[] Stoa(IntPtr strPtr, int strSize)
{
    var result = new byte[strSize];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(strPtr, result, 0, strSize);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    static byte [] ToByteArray(string str)
    {
        byte[] a = new byte[str.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = (byte)str[i];
        }
        return a; 
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] key = ToByteArray("abc");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (byte b in key)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("key[{0}] : {1}", i++, b);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
key[0] : 97
key[1] : 98
key[2] : 99
```

Comment: There is a cleaner way: `Byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc");`

Comment: @SebastianHofmann make this an answer and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Done, but there is no need to delete your answer. :)