# Wrong AES decryption when trying to decrypt in another language

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, aes

When I try to Encrypt in C++ and decrypt in C# it gives me an error

> The input data is not a complete block

But It doesn't make any sence to me, because if I try to decrypt the message in C++, the same language as I made the encryption it works fine.

So, some code from the C++ part:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 std::string szEncryptionKey = "Sixteen byte key";
 std::string szEncryptionIV = "Sixteen byte key";
 std::string str = "I do not like green eggs and ham I do not like them Sam-I-Am.";
 std::string str_encrypted = encrypt(str, szEncryptionKey, szEncryptionIV);
 std::string str_decrypted = decrypt(str_encrypted, szEncryptionKey, szEncryptionIV);

 std::cout << "str encrypted: " << str_encrypted << std::endl;
 std::cout << "str decrypted: " << str_decrypted << std::endl;

return 0;
}


std::string encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key, const std::string& iv)
{

  std::string str_out;
  CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());
  CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
    new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
        new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
            BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING
        )
     )
  );
 return str_out;
}
```

I'm taking the encrypted and base64 encoded string, and the KEY and IV to the C#:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Sixteen byte key");


            String msg2 = "cboiiqATFAU9KyK49BJMmkLLwiAyaP6yYjyM0oP09xbITLGaxRuLCsTYYzUKANydhO+JO7N00aVz0tmFTg==";
        byte[] msg = Convert.FromBase64String(msg2);
        DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(msg, bytes, bytes);

static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.

        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted = null;
            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
            {
                byte[] decryptedText = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

               String s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedText);

                Console.Write(s);
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
```

The error messages come at this line :

```
byte[] decryptedText = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
```

This line :

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Sixteen byte key");
```

It's just a guess with the UTF8, but I have no idea if it's the right encoding.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Your strings only contain chars within the ASCII set, therefore you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` or `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure that C++ version has no padding?

Comment: Is the input data an exact multiple of the block size, 16-bytes for AES? `msg2` when decoded is 61 bytes which is not a valid AES encrypted length.

Comment: @Evk Just added no padding, but still the same

Comment: @zaph Okay, yes it should be.. You know what might cause this? since it still works with the decryption in c++?

Comment: And what if you use padding, such as PKCS7 in C++?

Comment: Does it work with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes();`?

Comment: Yes, it does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input data is not an exact multiple of the block size, 16-bytes for AES. `msg2` when decoded is 61 bytes which is not a valid AES encrypted length, thus invalid and produces the error message: "The input data is not a complete block
".

AES is block based so if the data to be encrypted is not an exact multiple of the block size it must be padded. The general padding method used with AES is PKCS#7 sometimes named PKCS#5.

CFB mode requires padding, CFB8 mode does not.

Comment: You know what cause this problem?

Comment: But with the CFB mode, then padding should be none?

Comment: Yes, there is no padding applied because `BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING` is specified.

Comment: You need CFB8 for no padding, not just CFB. Better yet just use padding.

Comment: Thanks for helping me..
I changed the mode to CBC, and with padding_zeros.. And it works perfectly (y)

Comment: Zero padding is a not a good solution if the data to be encrypted can contain zeros (0x00).

Comment: What do you prefer instead?

Comment: [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) (sometimes called PKCS#5 in AES implementations, they are interchangeable). Generally CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding are the defaults in most implementations but it is always better to explicitly call out all options. Note: When using padding never return padding errors to the caller.